# Convert cooker supply to 13amp sockets

Tags: kitchens

I will shortly be having a range cooker installed that requires 2 x 13 amp supplies. Maximum power required is stated as 3 kW and 2.85 kW respectively. I have a redundant cooker supply on its own circuit, probably 30 amp. I would like to convert this to provide the power for the new cooker. Can you advise if this is possible please and what would be needed?

Comment: I am assuming it is the USA. Can it be connected to a 230V feed with a neutral and ground. That could be setup as two 120V 20A outlets.

Comment: @gil, with the info provided , if it was in the US that would be a huge code violation. Actually several. 13 amp is more likely UK

Comment: I think were in the 4-1/2 continent area of Euro-style power.  13A is a standard breaker size, and multiple circuits per appliance is for balance in 3-phase homes. (or 2-of-3-phase).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean BS1363 13A sockets, as used in the UK, then wiring them to a 30A supply is normal.  Use two separate 13A sockets, as your load is beyond the 20A total that a double socket can safely handle.

If you want to know how to wire them safely, consult an electrician.  What you need to buy depends on how you intend to mount the sockets - surface mounted or flush (with the back boxes buried in the wall).